# How to monitor hyperion services on linux

Tags: linux, rhel, hyperion

So to monitor outages we have been asked to monitor some critical Hyperion services running on our Linux exalytics server. 
I was thinking of setting up Tivoli or Hp sitescope on the servers to do that. Or may be setup a linux script via control-M process that would send notification in case any of the services listed below shuts down.
Would appreciate any suggestions.

List of the services to be monitored:

Workspace Agent

Workspace Framework Agent

Workspace IRLog

Workspace BIService

Workspace DAS

Planning RMI

Essbase Server

OHS

Answer (score 1):

We are setting up 'HP sitescope' to monitor the services. 
Just need to create a service ID for sitescope to grant login to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to effectively monitor Hyperion apps the solution is not as simple as monitoring ports or services. Hyperion has a mix of technologies across windows and Unixes and even versions of Hyperion. For apps that run on a J2EE platform such as WebLogic you need a process that will test that the application running under the java executable is "alive", there are several ways to do this. You could run the validation tool that comes with Hyperion, you could also use a script that parses the registry.html report for validation URLs and test those. The first option is the easiest, just run the validation tool and let it test all the parts of the LOCAL Hyperion system. You could take this step a bit further and integrate this tool into your own monitoring tool by parsing the output and doing something with it. Each test results in a **pass** **fail** status so it would be pretty simple to do. The Second method is to write your own script(s) and utilize the registry.html file as a configuration source and pick the pieces within that file that you like to monitor.

I've done the later using the registry.html file on Linux systems. You can check out my script that I use over here http://hackinghyperion.blogspot.com/2015/02/bash-script-to-check-validation-urls.html as well as here for a remote version http://hackinghyperion.blogspot.com/2015/02/remote-validation-url-check.html